# XML: Invalid characters inside KEY

Tags: xml, invalid-characters

I am reading some parameters and generating a XML file with them. I have read a lot about special characters that should be escaped, in particular I have a function that escapes all the characters for the VALUE in the XML file (when no using CDATA):

```
& ==> &amp;
< ==> &lt;
> ==> &gt;
" ==> &quot;
' ==> &apos;
```

In my specific case, there is only one case where the user can enter the value of the KEY, and the question is, should here be invalid these characters (even escaped)?
Example, the user introduces: `key => ipaddress> value=> 192.168.1.25`
Which would be the valid option:

```
<ipaddress>>192.168.1.25</ipaddress>>
or <ipaddress&gt;>192.168.1.25</ipaddress&gt;>
or should the ">" character be omitted for the final string?
```

Comment: If you are concatenating strings then you are not building an XML document. Use a proper API.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for the answer. I know what you mean, but in this scenario I had no choice. The question is more "theoretical", I wanted to know which characters should be avoided inside the KEY to ensure a "valid" XML-structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those will work, you would be much safer to use a fixed element name and put the key as an attribute:

```
<entry key="ipaddress&gt;">192.168.1.25</entry>
```

I would strongly recommend you use a proper XML aware API to write XML files, which will handle any necessary escaping for you automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is correct then that any of the 5 previously posted characters are legal inside the KEY in a XML tag? Of course the perfect way to proceed would be an appropriate API, as this is not possible right now, I would like to be awared of all the possible issues I should consider to avoid formatting problems for a well-formed XML document.

Comment: @estradjs The rules for what is allowed in element names can be found in [the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name). For English it's essentially letters, numbers, hyphen, dot and underscore, except that the first character must be a letter or underscore. Also the colon has a special meaning for namespaces and shouldn't be used for any other purpose. Conversely, attribute _values_ allow pretty much anything except control characters (though some escaping may be necessary).

Comment: @estradjs ... and if you use a proper API that escaping will be handled for you. Are you really sure you "have no choice"? Pretty much any programming language these days will have XML support, often you'll have several APIs to choose from.

Comment: Thanks for the link, this is a good way to check my options. Regarding the XML API, it is not possible mainly for the environment, it is a hardware appliance where I am trying to configure some services. The language allowed here is TCL, I need to run it without any libraries but with the standard language instead.